# Mac Terminal not returning correct Patterns with grep

Tags: bash, macos, grep

i'm attempting to clean a word list using scripting.
Starting out, i'm just trying to remove words with a '.' in them.

I've tried

```
grep -v "\." wlist_match1.txt
```

and

```
grep -v ‘\.’ wlist_match1.txt
```

and

```
grep -v \. wlist_match1.txt
```

It still returns a list of words with '.' in them for all commands. I'm not sure what to do. Even when I grep words I know are in the list, it will return an empty list so it appears grep is not working at all. Any hints?

Comment: The second one should work.

Comment: The second one does not use plain single quotes, but "curly" quotes

Comment: The first one works for me.

Comment: What does `type grep` say?

Comment: grep is hashed (/usr/bin/grep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have

```bash
$ cat file
1
1.5
2
```

Then (I'm using `/usr/bin/grep` to use the MacOS grep, not the GNU grep that occurs earlier in my PATH)

```bash
$ /usr/bin/grep -v "\." file
1
2
```

removed the line with the literal dot.

```bash
$ /usr/bin/grep -v \. file
```

removed all lines -- bare "slash-dot" becomes plain dot, and grep removes any line containing a character.

```bash
$ /usr/bin/grep -v ‘\.’ file
1
1.5
2
```

no lines removed because no lines contain the "fancy" quotes.

Do you not get the same results?